# Is there a "smart" way to handle the drawing order?

Tags: drawing, tile, depth, isometric

I'm working on an isometric game. I'ts been going pretty well so far.
One of the key features is a cam that can rotate 360 degrees around the player.

However, this makes depth calculations for handling the drawing order very hard.
I basically have to switch the order of the for-loops depending on which way the camera faces
(i.e. which two faces of an isometrically rendered cube are visible?)

I wonder if there is a smarter way to do this. If not, I'll have to use a lot of code that is very similar.

Comment: You might need to provide more information here. How are you doing things currently? Are you drawing using a 2D API (using sprites and such like?) or are you using a 3D API? What does 'camera can rotate 360 degrees around player' mean?

Comment: I am using 2D but this is simply a theoretical question. with rotating the camera 360 degrees I mean rotating it 360 around a compass, while the angle to the ground remains the same. The center of my 'view' is always the player.

Comment: In that case I too second Vallentin's answer below. You really ought to be using OpenGL if you want to this sort of manipulation. In that scheme of things, it will simply be a matter of orienting the virtual camera the way you need.

Comment: Already looking into it. Someone told me before that OpenGL would be good to get better performance. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The smarter way would be to use [OpenGL](http://www.opengl.org/).

- If you are using C++ or C, then just search only for the DLL libraries and import them into your project.
- If you are using Java, then take a look at either [LWJGL](http://www.lwjgl.org/) or [JOGL](https://jogamp.org/jogl/www/).

All the libraries etc. are completely free to use, and you can use them in any way you want.